# Function to count trailing zeroes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, algorithms, natural-numbers

Recently a friend of mine suggested a question, which was to find the number of trailing zeroes in $(100!)$.

While that should be easy enough to tackle, as I have seen a lot of questions on MSE that deal with exactly this type of problem, I would like to solve a more general problem:

**Define a function $f(n)$ using common mathematical operators and other notation that counts the number of trailing zeroes in a given positive integer $n$**

Now I have got something in mind, which is:
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor log_{10}x\rfloor} \left(1-|sgn(x\mod(10^i)|\right)$$
Where $sgn()$ is the [signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). The function is based on the concept of checking if the number is divisible by successive powers of $10$. Here’s a [Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9tp3ynpkcy) for the function.

While this does seem to work, I would like a more compact function that I can actually work with, while this is something like rewriting a computer algorithm, only using mathematical notation.

All ideas are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
As proposed in a comment by @RobertIsrael, another definition for the function is:

$$\min(v_{2}(n), v_{5}(n))$$

with reference to the [$p$-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation) of $n$.

Comment: It would be easy if you're allowed a function to find the prime decomposition.

Comment: @BenjaminWang I agree, but that won’t be a ‘common function’ anymore. Actually my target is to get a function that I can apply to get intuition about the type of questions: like to find the number of trailing zeroes in a factorial.

Comment: The number of trailing zeros in $n$ is $\min(\nu_2(n), \nu_5(n))$, where $\nu_2(n)$ is the $p$-adic order of $n$, i.e. the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $n$.  You might complain that this won't be a "common function", but it is exactly what you need to use in finding the number of trailing zeros in a factorial.

Comment: I guess so.  But I'm not sure defining a function rather than a simple concept is of any benefit.  I think I'd rather be told to "take the number of trailings zeros" and leave it to the reader to assume it can be done than to have scary looking function like that.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks for your insight. BenjaminWang ‘s comment says the same too. I think that then there may not be any other better way than the one you have proposed… Is there a way to think about your solution in a more intuitionistic way?

Comment: @fleablood that’s the thing exactly. My formulation lacks the beauty of ‘good and behaved formulae’. But instead of resorting to a literary response, my wish to create a ‘good’ function is merely to get a stronger foothold on the intuition, and because such formulae often provide a deeper insight into the problem.

Comment: In the case of $100!$, the essential insight is exactly the number of factors of $5$ and $2$, because you can easily show that in any factorial $n!$ there are always more factors of $2$ than of $5$, and therefore it comes down to just counting the factors of $5$, for which you can use simple reasoning about how a factorial is defined. I would expect most of the "number of trailing zeros" questions that have intuitive answers to be answerable in a similar way.

Comment: To put it another way, Robert Israel's formula is a **very** intuitive way to approach problems of this kind. I really don't think you will find a better answer.

Comment: As number of trailing zeros is only a quirky byproduct of divisibility be $10$ I'd say the only acceptable "good behaved" function that gets to a "foothold" would be one that checks the prime factorization of the number and counts the min power of $2$ and $5$.  I'd say Robert Israel's is the only possible answer that would in anyway be relevant.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. I agree on the approach of Robert Israels’s formula and have appended it to the end of my question. Actually I have only heard about $p$-adics recently and don’t think that I have got the essence of it yet…

Comment: @DavidK and all others in this discussion, can anyone refer to a resource (preferably online) which approaches the $p$-adics with a more intuitionistic way? Actually I like to get the feel of a topic before proceeding with the formulae and other details.

Comment: @DavidK and just to be sure, you are referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) right?

Comment: And by the way, I am still not sure why I have been writing ‘intuitionistic’ instead of ‘intuitive’ from the beginning…

Comment: It really has very little to do with the $p$-adics in general.  $\nu_p(x)$ is a very intuitive concept: it's how many times you can divide $x$ evenly by $p$.

Answer (score 0):

The $f(n)$ you specify as the number of trailing zeroes of $n$ is the highest power of $10$ that divides $n$.

One way to construct such a function uses the following facts:

- Divisibility of $n$ by $10^k$ can be tested by checking whether $$n = 10^k\left\lfloor\displaystyle\frac{n}{10^k}\right\rfloor \quad\text{or, equivalently, whether}\quad n- 10^k\left\lfloor\displaystyle\frac{n}{10^k}\right\rfloor = 0$$
- The function $0^{\left|x\right|}$ has the convenient property that the output will be $1$ when $x=0$ and $0$ otherwise. If you prefer, this is an instance of the "[Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)", $\delta_{x0}$.

$$0^{\left|x\right|} \, =\, \delta_{x0} \, =\, \begin{cases}
1 &\text{ if }x=0 \\
0 &\text{ if }x \neq 0
\end{cases}$$

These two facts together allow us to express $f(n)$ as a sum as follows:

$$f(n) = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\log_{10}n\right\rfloor} \, 0^{\,\left|\,n-10^k\left\lfloor\displaystyle\frac{n}{10^k}\right\rfloor\,\right|}$$

Each summand will add $1$ to the total, until $10^k$ no longer divides $n$, at which point any remaining summands will add $0$. In this way, the function counts the number of trailing zeroes of $n$.

This is a fun expression, but it isn't very practically useful.

Comment: Actually your expression of $0^{|x|}$ was implemented in my function as $1-|sgn(x)|$

Comment: While the divisibility is checked by the mod function.

Comment: Yes, I see now that this function works in the exact same way as yours! Just a rephrasing. I don't think there will be a nice closed-form expression, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Agreed. A closed-form would really be nice, but according to the comments on my question, it appears that the chances are close to nil.